# Refresh div with button click using random javascript string element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

There are several similar questions, so I hope this is a unique problem. None of the proposed solutions on those similar questions have solved my issue. Humble apologies from this beginner if I messed up somehow.

I have an empty div on my page with I am loading using javascript with strings from an array. Currently, I have a script running on a button which reloads the entire page. I would like for that button to just reload the div with items from my javascript array.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="obliqueStyle.css">
<style></style>
</head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="strategyBox"></div>

         <div id="button">
         <a class="againbutton" onclick="buttonReload()">Again</a>

            <script>
                   var buttonReload = function() {
                        document.getElementById("strategyBox").innerHTML = '<p id="strategyText">' + randomStrategy + '</p>';
                   }
            </script>
         </div>

        </div>
        <script src="os.js"></script>

    </body>
```

Here is a snippet of my array and the JS (coming from the os.js file referenced in index.html) I am using to load the div initially/on refresh:

```
var obliqueStrategy = ["Abandon normal instruments",
                   "Accept advice",
                   "Accretion",
                   "A line has two sides"];


var randomStrategy = obliqueStrategy[Math.floor(Math.random() * obliqueStrategy.length)];


                   document.getElementById("strategyBox").innerHTML = '<p id="strategyText">' + randomStrategy + '</p>';
```

I've tried calling the same javascript as a function in script in the html like this:

```
<div id="button">
         <a class="againbutton" onclick="buttonReload()">Again</a>

            <script>
                   var buttonReload = function() {
                        document.getElementById("strategyBox").innerHTML = '<p id="strategyText">' + randomStrategy + '</p>';
                   }
            </script>
         </div>
```

I've tried using the jQuery AJAX load function like this:

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            $("#againbutton").on("click", function() {
            $("#strategyBox").load("index.html")
            return false;
            })
        })
</script>
```

I've played around with variations of the above and tried a couple other things that I'm forgetting exactly how and what I did, so I can't include them. I've really hit a wall on this even though it seems profoundly simple.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one method: http://jsfiddle.net/kxqcws07/

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="strategyBox"><p id="strategyText"></p></div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" class="againbutton" value="Again">
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
//wrapping your logic in a namespace helps reduce the chances of naming collisions of functions and variables between different imported js files 
var localNameSpace = function() {
    //private array containing our strings to randomly select
    var obliqueStrategy = [
        "Abandon normal instruments"
        , "Accept advice"
        , "Accretion"
        , "A line has two sides"
    ];

    var api = {
        //bindButtonAction binds the generateRandomStrategy function to the click event of the againbutton
        bindButtonAction: function() {
            $('#wrapper .againbutton').click(api.generateRandomStrategy);
        }
        , generateRandomStrategy: function() {
            //get the position of one of the string randomly
            //Math.random() returns a float value < 1 so multiplying it by 100 gets us a range of (0.* - 99.*)
            //then we Math.floor() that to get rid of the float value and keep just the integer part
            //finally we modulus it with the length of the string array
            //if you are unfamiliar with modulus, what it does is gives you the remainder of a division.  for instance 10 / 3 gives you 3 with a remainder of 1, so 10 % 3 would be just 1.
            //what this does for us is keeps the random offset of our within the bounds of the array length (0 to length -1)
            var randomOffset = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) % obliqueStrategy.length;
            //finally once we have the offset, we set the html to the string at the position in the array
            $('#wrapper #strategyBox #strategyText').html( obliqueStrategy[randomOffset] );
        }
    };

    return api;
}();

$(document).ready(function() {
    //here we call the bind action so the button will work, but we also explicitly call the generateRandomStrategy function so the page will preload with a random string at the start
    localNameSpace.bindButtonAction();
    localNameSpace.generateRandomStrategy();
});
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. It does indeed work. Would you mind walking me through what's going on here? Without taking too much of your time, was I on the right track at all?